# Shorthand way for assigning object properties in Groovy?

Tags: class, object, groovy, variable-assignment

I create Groovy objects using this convention...

```
Item item1 = new Item( name: "foo", weight: "150")
```

...is there a shorthand convention for manipulating properties object? something like this...

```
item1( name: "hello", weight: "175") //this does not work, btw ;-)
```

...instead of...

```
item1.name = "hello"
item1.weight = "175"
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have the `with` method, [as described by the great Mr Haki](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/mrhaki/~3/Vx6FGAEWt5I/groovy-goodness-with-method.html)

```
item1.with{
    name = "hello"
    weight = "175"
}
```

Comment: @RaffiM for Groovy and Grails users, he is great. (his blog is great)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
item1.metaClass.setProperties(item1, [name: "hello", weight: "175"])
```

Comment: You may also do something like `[name: "hello", weight: "175"].each { item1[it.key] = it.value }` if the object does not override the `setAt` mehod or `[name: "hello", weight: "175"].each { item1.setProperty it.key, it.value }`.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer **item1.with** if I have concrete variables to change

```
item1.with {
    name = "lalal"
    weight = 86
    high = 100
}
```

I prefer **InvokerHelper.setProperties** when I have map of properties (can be any size)

```
@ToString
class Item{
    def name
    def weight
}
Item item1 = new Item( name: "foo", weight: "150")

println "before: $item1"
use(InvokerHelper) {
    item1.setProperties weight: 22, name: "abc"
}
println "after : $item1"
```

Output:

```
before: Item(foo, 150)
after : Item(abc, 22)
```