# Why can I call a method without a dot in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I noticed that I can call methods without the `.` symbol, but I can't find anything in the documentation about it. Could you tell me how it works or point to the documentation?

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    def person = new Person()
    person.setName "Socrates" setAge 20
}

class Person {
    Person setName (name) {
        return this
    }

    Person setAge (age) {
        return this
    }
}
```

Comment: Pointing to documentation is not hard: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/, but I do fail to find the correct chapter 

Comment: @Luuk I wouldn't ask if it was that simple)

Comment: This look like a great extension of this old question/answer : [Shorthand way for assigning object properties in Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507742/shorthand-way-for-assigning-object-properties-in-groovy)

Comment: Omitting dots is especially a nice feature for writing DSLs, see [docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html)

Comment: @IWilms Yes, thanks, create a regular answer so I can mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature that is especially meant for writing your own Domain-Specific Languages. Chained method calls can be turned into sentence like syntax.

From the [Groovy DSL docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html):

> "command chain" feature extends this by allowing us to chain such parentheses-free method calls, requiring neither parentheses around arguments, nor dots between the chained calls.

Example (from the docs):

```
// equivalent to: turn(left).then(right)
turn left then right
```

Example (from the talk *Groovy: The Awesome Parts* by Paul King):

```
// equivalent to: move(forward).at(3.getKm().div(h))
move forward at 3.km/h
```

And here is a simple example how to make that work:

```
String forward = "forward"
Integer.metaClass.getKm = { return delegate * 1000 }
int h = 3600

move(forward).at(3.getKm().div(h))
move forward at 3.km/h


def move(String direction){
  return new Vehicle(direction: forward)
}


class Vehicle{
    String direction
    def at(speedInMeterPerSecond){
        println "moving $direction with $speedInMeterPerSecond m/s"
    }
}
```

prints

```
moving forward with 0.8333333333 m/s
moving forward with 0.8333333333 m/s
```